# In shooting, what is a MOA (minute of angle)?

Tags: terminology, guns, shooting

In hunting/shooting, you will often see the term MOA (which stands for minute of angle).

What exactly is an (MOA) minute of angle when it comes to shooting?

Comment: Note that *MOA* also stands for "**minute of arc**," which [fortunately means the same thing](http://ballistipedia.com/index.php?title=Angular_Size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **minute of angle is a measure of an angle**. It is **1/60th of a degree**, 1/21600th of a circle.

Often times you will see this in

- Scope increments, 1/8 of an MOA is more precise than 1/4.
- Scope vertical adjustment range
- The ticks on a mil-dot reticle scope are usually given in MOA.
- The size of the dot on a reflex or red dot sight.
- The accuracy of a firearm, smaller or even sub-moa is better.

In regards to distance, **one MOA corresponds to 1.047 inches per 100 yards**, so 1 inch at 100 yards and 3 inches at 300 yards.

This can be useful to know when sighting in if you are 2 inches low at 100 yards, you need to move the scope up 2 MOA for 8 increments on a 1/4 MOA increment scope.

MOA can also be used for ranging targets with the right scope, a 12-inch prairie dog will be 12 MOA tall at 100 yards and 6 MOA at 200 yards.

Comment: You somehow missed the joke answer "60 seconds of angle, of course" :) Back to being serious; it would be helpful to link to the geometrical concept arcsecond, which is here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc